How to determine I've left a page
When I click to go to a page other than the page displaying my map, I get an event that the map size has changed. That event then calls an event that re-renders the map. That returns the page to the page with the map on it.
This event is fired by the map control so I have no control over its being fired.
Is it safe to look at NavigationManager.Uri and if it is to a different page (the new page starting to render), then ignore this message?
Or is there an event fired to the page being left?
